# When working with paths to server files, when is it necessary to use back or forward slashes (single or double)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, iis, path

Regarding the following code sample:

```
string baseLocation = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/");
const string templateName = @"//temp//ExportTemplate.xlsx";
const string generatedLocation = @"{0}//temp//{1}";
var fileName = string.Format("Export-{0}.xlsx", DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
var newFile = String.Format(generatedLocation, baseLocation, fileName);
File.Copy(baseLocation + templateName, newFile, true);
```

We are using this on a production server and a local dev environment (via a site in IIS). Both are running IIS 7.5. The code works correctly on production, but throws an error in local dev:

```
Access to the path 'C:\Path\To\Site\//temp//Export-2013-01-29.xlsx' is denied.
```

The file is created/copied correctly on local dev, but I'm guessing it's erroring out due to the slashes in the path being incorrect. The app pool identity has full access to the 'temp' folder.

This brings up a couple questions:

- In this situation, what does the '//' do to path? I understand '\' is the way to escape a backslash, but the '//' doesn't make sense.
- Could there be a difference in the configuration of the two environments that makes the generated path work correctly on the production server but fail in my local dev?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should be using a \, not / for file paths.
Either

```
const string templateName = @"\temp\ExportTemplate.xlsx";
```

or

```
const string templateName = "\\temp\\ExportTemplate.xlsx";
```

would work fine. It's surprising the current version of the code works in production,it may be due to that windows is built to allow either forward or back slashes in file paths. (this goes back to DOS days when many of the users were also UNIX users)

In addition, I'd recommend using `Path.Combine` rather than just concatenating the strings for the file path (this will get help avoid getting extra slashes or forward slashes in paths like "C:\Path\To\Site\\temp\Export-2013-01-29.xlsx"). ex:

```
File.Copy(Path.Combine(baseLocation, templateName), newFile, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

// will always give you // ... With the @ at the string, it is a verbatim string literal and you do not need to escape characters. Therefore you can use \ to get .  If you drop the @, you will need to use \ to get .  When you are working with file paths, it is always a backslash().  When working with URL paths, it is always a forward slash(/)