# Crystal Reports in MVC throwing exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, crystal-reports

I am loading report in mvc4 using following code. but its throwing error on Exporting. Error is "The system cannot find the path specified."

Please guide me ; remember its not find file path

[image]

```
 ReportClass rptH = new ReportClass();
         rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/CrReports/CrProductsList.rpt");
         rptH.Load();
         rptH.SetDataSource(new ReportingFactory().AllProductsReport());

     Stream stream =rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
     return File(stream, "application/pdf");
```

this line throwing error

```
Stream stream =rptH.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try back slashes instead of forward slashes (that's what I use)

```
rptH.FileName = Server.MapPath("~\CrReport\CrProductsList.rpt");
```

Here's what I use:

```
rptH.FileName = @"~\App_Pages\Secure\CrReports\CrProductsList.rpt";
```

See here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14592492/1438215

Edit: another thing to consider, *if* your reports directory is not a subdirectory of your solution, make sure the account IIS uses to run the application has read access to the CrReport folder.

Comment: thanx for your reply.  path is perfectly ok. i think its the table name used in report designing. I have created a Table and named as the table in report then its worked perfectly okay.